# SchemaCrawler couldn't connect to Oracle base

Tags: oracle, jdbc, database-connection, schemacrawler

Schemacrawler couldn't connect to Oracle base. The cmd line is below:

```
java -classpath ../../_schemacrawler/lib/*;lib/* schemacrawler.Main -url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:port:sid -u=user_name -password=pw -infolevel=minimum -schemas=target_schema -c=count -loglevel=CONFIG
```

And error is

```
Could not find a suitable JDBC driver for databse connection URL, jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:port:sid
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't seem to have the Oracle driver (e.g. ojdbc7.jar) in your class path. [The documentation](https://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/database-support.html) says the Oracle driver has to be downloaded separately; have you done that, and if so where have you put it?

Comment: Alex Poole, thanks for your reply. I've already put ojdbc14.jar in schemacrawler\lib\. Any ideas?

Comment: You're probably be better off commenting on @SualehFatehi's answer if you're already following the instructions. Why such an old version though?

Comment: I've put ojdbc6.jar and changed cmd line: `java -classpath ../../_schemacrawler/lib/*;lib/* schemacrawler.Main -driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver -url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:1521/sid -u=user -password=pw -infolevel=minimum -schemas=target_schema -c=count` and it's succeed!!! Thanks a lot!!! Although, I'm not sure what was mistake - wrong cmd or not suitable ojdbc version.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex Poole says, you need to download the Oracle JDBC driver, and place it in the SchemaCrawler lib folder. Please read the documentation on the [Database System Support](http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/database-support.html) page very carefully. Also, please make sure that you are using the latest version of Java 8, and the latest version of SchemaCrawler.

Sualeh Fatehi, SchemaCrawler